# htaccess subdomain 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've got what I considered to be a simple to fix issue where I want all the traffic from one subdomain redirected (301) to another subdomain (both on the same domain).

I've currently got this line in .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 news.domain.com blog.domain.com
```

but that throws a 500 error.

I'm totally lost with this and can't find any basic "this is how you redirect a to b" types of help.  Everything I've looked at seems really convoluted and massively overkill for what I believe to be such a simple task.

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the hostname/domain in the apache `Redirect` directive, you'll have to match against the `%{HTTP_HOST}` using a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^news\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon.  That works great on the root of the subdomain, but not for subfolders.  `http://news.domain.com/folder/page` doesn't get redirected (for example).

Comment: @Archer do you have other htaccess files or rewrite rules in the subfolder?

Comment: Bosh - thanks Jon.  Yes, there were other rewrite rules in there.  Moving the above script to the top has resolved all my problems.  Thanks a lot for your help, and for teaching me some new stuff :)